# How to know what is the namespace, url, soap action and method name?

Tags: php, android, web-services

I'm developing an android application that can connect to a web service but I can't start because the one who create the web service on server side gave me only this type of code using the php.

**Here's the code:**

```
try {
$client = new SoapClient("http://as2.abc.com/aerv/app/custom/comp/ec.wsdl",
array("location" => "http://as2.abc.com/aerv/app/custom/comp/ecsoap.php") );
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Caught exception: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n"; exit();
}
```

To be able to start in client side I need to know what is the namespace, url, soap action and method name in the given code. Please help me.

Comment: open wsdl file and there will be all such details.

Comment: more information is on - http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the link that explains all the parameters
[JAVA tutorials point link](http://javatutorialspoint.blogspot.in/2012/02/android-web-service-access-using-ksoap2.html)

And it will show you how to retrieve them.

SOAP_ACTION : It is your NAMESPACE/METHOD_NAME e.g. "http://microsoft.com/webservices/"

METHOD_NAME : It's the name of the Method e.g : "GetData", "GetUserDetails"

NAMESPACE : It's your NameSapce e.g: "http://microsoft.com/webservices/"

URL : 192.168.22.12/test/getMyData.asmx, your URL to web Services page