# What could be the reason for the Soap Fault (faultcode: soapenv:Client, faultstring:Bad Request)

Tags: android, debugging, soap-client, android-ksoap2, soapfault

I am writing a client to consume a SOAP web service in Android using ksoap2. And I have received a SOAP FAULT exception. Here is an excerpt from the LogCat.

```
<soapenv:Body><soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>soapenv:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Bad request</faultstring></soapenv:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
04-06 09:04:09.693: E/SearchPublications(1159): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soapenv:Client' faultstring: 'Bad request' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

This is how I extracted the values of the final strings from the WSDL:

- `Namespace`: The value of the attribute `namespace` of `xsd:import`
  element, which is a child element of `xsd:schema`, which is a child
  element of `types`
- `SoapAction`: Namespace appended by the method's name
- `MethodName`: The name of the method in the API
- `URL`: The actual URL of the WSDL

(Reference: [This answer and the link mentioned in it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582385/how-to-know-what-is-the-namespace-url-soap-action-and-method-name/19582525#19582525))

***I understand that there is something wrong with my code, but can anyone say what might be causing it and if I have set the values of the mentioned final variables correctly?***

I tried by setting the `dotnet` flag as `true` and `false` as well. I am trying to get the response in an `SoapObject` as it is an XML document, and I have read in an article that if the result is in XML, use `SoapObject`.

I also tried to debug it, and all the variables are apparently having their correct values (as shown in the debug perspective) before this line:

```
result= (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
```

At this line, a SoapFault excetion is thrown; you can compare the following piece of code and the screenshot. Can somebody suggest why this might be occurring and what else to try to fix it?

```
try{
result = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();
} catch (Throwable e) {
```

[image]

Comment: seems like you haven't entered correct parameters in your request.
you should create a soapObject and add properties you need to send.